# whats is the meaning of using exec and then read in ksh script

Tags: unix, ksh

THe script is like 
exec 8< $SEQ_FILE
read -u8 DATE SEQ_NUMBER
Can you please help me in understanding what this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exec 8< $SEQ_FILE` opens the file `$SEQ_FILE` for reading and associates it with file descriptor `8`.  All further commands can then read from that file descriptor.

The command `read -u8 DATE SEQ_NUMBER` then does exactly that.  It reads one line from that file and puts the line into two variables (split according to shell rules, typically at a space).