# How to print log messages in a ksh function that I want to read from?

Tags: ksh

Say I have a function:

```
function doSomeWork
{
    #work, work, work
    echo "$result1 $result2"
}
```

Now I am reading the results from that function using read like this:

```
doSomeWork | read r1 r2
echo "result1: r1, result2: r2"
```

Which works nicely, but now I cant output any other log messages using echo because it will screw the reading of results.

How can I write log messages inside doSomeWork without interfering with read?

---

Edit: here a demo of the approach

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "7 54" | read T1 T2
echo "T1 $T1 T2 $T2"
```

Comment: use the `ksh` specific `print` command instead of `echo`, `man print` and search for `file descriptor`. I don't have time to research now, this may also require a setup step with `exec`. Look at `[ksh] exec` answers here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753477/whats-is-the-meaning-of-using-exec-and-then-read-in-ksh-script?s=2|42.4501 looks like it will help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to use a *named pipe* (FIFO) instead of an anonymous one.  Not always the right solution, but maybe it will give you some ideas:

```
pipe_name=/tmp/mypipe$$
mkfifo "$pipe_name"

function doSomeWork
{

    result1='result1'
    result2='result2'
    echo "work, work, work"
    echo "$result1 $result2" > "$pipe_name"
}

doSomeWork &             # running in background, otherwise it would block
read r1 r2 < "$pipe_name"
echo "result1: r1, result2: r2"

rm "$pipe_name"
```

Gives:

```
work, work, work
result1: r1, result2: r2
```

If you had many function calls then you would only create/destroy the pipe once.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Your fifo gave me a nice idea, so I give you an upvote: The named pipe can also give intermediate results. 
Change the function `doSomeWork()` into `...; echo "$result1" > "$pipe_name"; sleep 2; echo work; sleep 2; echo "$result2" > "$pipe_name"; }` and the main code into 
`read r1 < "$pipe_name"; echo "r1=$r1"; read r2 < "$pipe_name"; echo "r2: $r2"`.
The first result is already returned while the function is still working !

Comment: Great!  Named pipes are often overlooked as a flexible mechanism for interprocess communication too.

Answer (score 2):

You can write other log messages to stderr.
Another solution is making sure the output can be filtered:

Using tail

```
function doSomeWork
{
    echo "work, work, work"
    result1=1
    result2=2
    echo "More work"
    echo "$result1 $result2"
}

doSomeWork | tail -1 | read r1 r2
echo "result1: ${r1}, result2: ${r2}"
```

With grep

```
function doSomeWork
{
    echo "work, work, work"
    result1=1
    result2=2
    echo "More work"
    echo "Result $result1 $result2"
}

doSomeWork | grep Result | read dummy r1 r2
echo "result1: ${r1}, result2: ${r2}"
```